# Как создать шаблонный алиас?

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Хочу сделать проверку типа итератора каким-то таким способом:

```
template <typename It, typename T>
using is = std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category, T>::value;
```

И потом использовать это дело в ассертах (`RanIt` - шаблонный тип):

```
static_assert(is<RanIt, std::random_access_iterator_tag>, "random access required");
```

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Либо замените `using` на `constexpr bool`, либо уберите из определения `::value` и перенесите его в место проверки.

`using` - не константа, а алиас. Может быть синонимом типа, внутри которого определена константа `value`, но сам не может быть константой.